# Crashed by app and tried to re-load it, however getting new weird Django Requests error

Tags: django, request

My Django app was running before. My system crashed and I reloaded the app from Github.

Currently, my Django app has package 'requests', however, it can't seem to recognize this requests line in my settings file

```
settings.py
MIDDLEWARE = [

...
'request.middleware.RequestMiddleware',

]
```

Here is the error that I get:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'request.middleware'
```

pip3 list:

```
requests 2.22.0
```

Comment: have tou added `requests` in Installed Apps?

Comment: Yes, it's there. I did pip3 list and requests is in there.

Comment: i mean django's INSTALLED_APPS

Comment: Yup, it's there. I'm wondering if it could be a version issue with requests.

Comment: https://pypi.org/project/requests-middleware/

Comment: I haven't used requests middleware, what's it about?

Comment: I'm not using requests middleware either, this should work with just requests.

Comment: you can just `import requests` in django

Comment: Yes, requests is there, but this line still does not work.